# Error running C:/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

Tags: latex, rstudio, pdflatex, sweave

I'm using latex in RStudio and when I try to compile pdf I get this message:

> Error running C:/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

I have reinstalled R, RStudio and miktex, but the problem persists. I have used

```
enter code here
Sys.which("pdflatex")

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\miktex 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

to update PATH, but the problem persists.

The code I'm trying to compile is this (it's a .Rnw file):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

hellow world!


\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What (error) messages do you get *before* the quoted one?

Comment: And which command do you use? You are working with rmd?

Comment: @RalfStubner, the entire mensage is this:                                                 Writing to file teste.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on 'teste.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on teste.tex...failed
Error running C:/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

Comment: @Christoph, I don't know. How can I know if I'm working with rmd?

Comment: Something like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316165/137734)? Please include the file you want to make with Latex. A Rmd ends with`.rmd`, a TEX file with `.tex`...

Comment: Please post a [mre] including file name with extension and tell us which button in RStudio you are pressing.

Comment: @Christoph, the file I want to transform in pdf has extension '.tex'. I also tried with a .Rnw file and get the same problem. The .tex file has this code: ``` \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\input{stack_test-concordance}

Hellow World!

\end{document} ```                                                                                                                                                        
In TexWorks this code (without second and fourth line) is compiled into pdf normally, but not in Rstudio.

Comment: @RalfStubner, the file I'm trying to compile into pdf has this name: `stack_test2.tex`       I'm pressing the `Compile PDF` in Rstudio. The code present in `stack_test2.tex` file is this: ``` \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\input{stack_test2-concordance}

Hello World!


\end{document}  ```                                                                                                  
It works normally in Texworks editor, but not in Rstudio.

Comment: Please include the document. You can edit your question. Perhaps the two lines cause a problem in texworks? You still die not show which command throws the error message.

Comment: Please make a real [mre] (we don't have `stack_test-concordance.tex`) and [edit] your question to include it. Is there a file `stack_text2.log`? Any error messages in there?

Comment: BTW, the message "Writing to file teste.tex Processing code chunks with options ... " indicates that the `Sweave` command is used before `pdflatex` is called, which is typical for a `Rnw` file. Do you get the same output from a `tex` file?

Comment: @RalfStubner, I get the same problem with both .Rnw and .tex file. And I never get this mensage: "Writing to file teste.tex Processing code chunks with options ... "

Comment: @Christoph, I edited my question. I included the code I'm Trying to compile into pdf.

Comment: Yesterday I have uninstalled and installed again both miktex, rstudio and r, and the same problem persists.

Comment: You were the one citing that message in your first comment. I hate to ask again: What is the full output you get when pressing `Compile PDF` for the `Rnw` and for the `tex` file? Is there a `log` file and what is its content?